# Go Test - empty coverage file

Tags: go, testing

I have a go project, test directory contains a single sample test file. 
Few Functions of the test file are

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    setup()
    code := m.Run()
    shutdown()
    os.Exit(code)
}
func TestUserLogin(t *testing.T) {
    //sample code to make api call and validate response
}
func setup() {
    //start service
}
func shutdown() {
    //stop service
}
```

I want to see/generate a coverage report. The following command is being used to run tests:

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out
```

Output on terminal is

```
PASS
coverage: 100.0% of statements
```

coverage.out is getting generated but it consists of only single line

```
mode: set
```

coverage.out should have information about the files, lines, etc.

Anything that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: hi skikant, if you follow the manual at https://blog.golang.org/cover i guess it should be pretty straighfoward.. are your functions signature according to spec? They should starts with the "Test" and have a sole formal parameter of type *testing.T

Comment: It's pretty impossible to debug code we can't see.

Comment: "a go project which consists of a single sample test file" - is it really just the test file? Or is there also a non-test code file? If it's just the test file, then of course the coverage report is empty - there is no code to show coverage for.

Comment: @Victor - functions are according to spec, test are running file. Coverage report is not getting generated.
Flimzy - added few functions of test file.
Adrian - there are many non test code files, there is a single test file which contains few tests.

Comment: @skirant, show us the code in order to try to help you further... as i fas i read i have no other clues on what is going on

Answer (score 1):

> test directory contains a single sample test file

Here it is, Go coverage does not work if your *_test.go files are not in the same directory a.k.a they have been put in another folder.

Comment: what do you mean by a.k.a ?

Answer (score 1):

in general tests and codes should be in the same package to generate coverage report. if not you need to pass `-coverpkg=./...`  .

for example:

```
 go test -race -p 1 -coverpkg=./... ./... -coverprofile=cover.out
```